# PHP - XML completo no var_dump

Tags: php, xml

Boa tarde, estou querendo ver o `xml` completo vindo de uma resposta do web service SOAP, mas quando coloco `var_dump` mostra só a metade dele, a outra parte é substituída pela palavra "`... (length=740)`". 
Como faço para ver ele completo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imprimir o xml advindo de um `file_get_contents` é possivel com um simples `echo`

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/rss');
echo $file;
```

Há mais duas formas:

```
print ($file);
```

ou usando o método asXML:

```
$xml->asXML('filename.xml');
```

Para trabalhar com asXML você deve ter um objeto SimpleXMLElement que pode ser visto nesta decoumentação: [Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

**OBS:** se você tem o xdebug instalado ele irá truncar o resultado do `var_dump` para prevenir crashes do browser, este é o link da informação [Link](http://xdebug.org/docs/display)

> There is a number of settings that control the output of Xdebug's
>   modified var_dump() function: xdebug.var_display_max_children,
>   xdebug.var_display_max_data and xdebug.var_display_max_depth.

Comment: Quando coloco echo, ele não mostra as tag.

Comment: Aqui não tem o método asXML

Comment: @ÁlyssonAlexandre adicionei mais informações

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo, valeu.